# Converting a decimal number x > 1 with n decimals to binary (for example: 70,5)

Tags: binary, discrete-mathematics

For homework I am to convert a decimal number to binary. This is usually pretty easy, but I have no idea how to it with a number like 70,5.
I know that there is the multiplication algorithm for x < 1, but here, x > 1. I was thinking about maybe writing 70,5 as a sum of numbers that are < 1, then find the binary expressions of these and take the sum. But I'm not sure this is the right approach.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it!! Just find the binary of 70 (1000110), the binary of .5 (.1) and put them together like 1000110.1 :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).